# Trouble With frmMenu.controls( control ) code but for forms

Tags: vba, forms, excel

Sorry for the bad title but I do not know how to say this as English is my second language.

I have a form called "frmMenu" with a textbox called "txtName".

I have the code in a module:

```
Public Sub TextMenu(ByVal SomeVariable As String)
frmMenu.controls(SomeVariable).text="hi"
end sub
```

I am calling the module with the parameter "txtName" to point to the textbox on the form

if I have many forms with the same textbox name, how can I point to many forms? something similar to the ".controls" code but for forms.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through all Loaded UserForms in `VBA.UserForms` collection and on each control on the form.

You can have a function return the control by providing its name.

```
Public Function ControlByName(ByVal Name As String) As Object

    Dim f As UserForm, c As Control

    For Each f In VBA.UserForms
        For Each c In f.Controls
            If c.Name = Name Then
                Set ControlByName = f.Controls(Name)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    Next
End Function
```

Then to call it:

```
Sub T()

    Dim f As TextBox2
    Set f = ControlByName("TextBox1")

    Debug.Print f.Text

    Dim b As CommandButton
    Set b = ControlByName("CommandButton1")

    Debug.Print b.Caption
End Sub
```